# How to just color a chosen text in Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I would like to color just a chosen text of my document. However, even though when I specified that the coloring (blue, particularly) was only applied within the bracket `{}`, the rest of my document all turned blue.

I tried to use `\par` or even `\quad`. It did not work.

When I tried `\textcolor{blue}{my text}`, it worked for that only specific instance.

However, when I tried

```
    \color{blue}__Answer:__

    1+1

    $$
    x_1 + x_2 = 2x_3^{2}
    $$

    \quad
```

That block of text is colored blue and so is the rest of the document, which is not what I want.

**Below is what I have in my Rmarkdown document**

```
Question 1

Let $x_1$ and $x_2$ be two random variables with covariance matrix:
$$
\boldsymbol{\Sigma} =
\begin{pmatrix}
    7        & \sqrt{5} \\
    \sqrt{5} & 3
\end{pmatrix}
$$Find the principal components (eigenvalues and eigenvectors) and compute the percentage of the total variance explained by each component.

\color{blue}__Answer:__

$$
x_1 + x_2 = 2x_3^{2}
$$

\quad

Question 2: 

work through their Eating in the UK example about food in the United Kingdom work through their Eating in the UK example about food in the United Kingdom work through their Eating in the UK example about food in the United Kingdom
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `\color{black}` after the `\quad` immediately preceding "Question 2:", that should give you the desired effect.

```
\color{blue}__Answer:__

$$
x_1 + x_2 = 2x_3^{2}
$$

\quad

\color{black}

Question 2:
```

Comment: Cheers!  It is a little clunky since you have to re-declare `\color{blue}` / `\color{black}` every time.  You could create a custom command (like "answer") and call that with `\begin{answer}` and `\end{answer}`, but this should do for now.